# Unable to quit Quarkus dev mode when using s3 Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, quarkus

I am on MacOS and using Quarkus 3.4.1. Whenever I use quarkus dev mode (entered via mvnw quarkus:dev) and press 'q' or 'control-c' I successfully exit the dev mode. However, whenever I try to do anything with the S3Client, I can no longer exit dev mode. This happened with local S3 on docker, or a real connection when I disable dev services.

My code:

```
@Inject
    S3Client s3;

    @ConfigProperty(name = "bucket.name")
    String bucket;

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public TenantProperties storeTenantProperties(TenantProperties tenantProperties) throws Exception {
        PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucket)
                .key(String.format("%s-tenantProperty", tenantProperties.getId())).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.fromString(tenantProperties.toString());
        PutObjectResponse putObjectResponse = s3.putObject(putObjectRequest, requestBody);
        if(putObjectResponse.sdkHttpResponse().isSuccessful()) {
            return tenantProperties;
        }
        s3.close();
        throw new Exception();
    }
```

I also tried adding

```
void onStop(@Observes ShutdownEvent ev) {
        s3.close();
    }
```

Which didn't change anything. What isn't being closed?

I even added

```
quarkus.shutdown.timeout=10
```

to application.properties, but still nothing changed.

Hot swap also seems to break when this happens. Also happens when I do things other than upload with S3Client, even something simple like list buckets.

Comment: Very interesting! Mind opening an issue on Quarkus Github with sample application that behaves as you describe so we can investigate?